# How To get TOP 5 value in SQL with multiple same output that exceed the limit 5

Tags: php, mysql

```
    Database 1           Database 2 
||==============||    ||==============||
||user || value ||    ||user || value ||
||-----||-------||    ||-----||-------||
|| 1   ||  50   ||    || 1   ||  50   ||
|| 2   ||  50   ||    || 2   ||  50   ||
|| 3   ||  50   ||    || 3   ||  40   ||
|| 4   ||  40   ||    || 4   ||  40   ||
|| 5   ||  40   ||    || 5   ||  30   ||
|| 6   ||  40   ||    || 6   ||  20   ||
|| 7   ||  40   ||    || 7   ||  20   ||
|| 8   ||  30   ||    || 8   ||  10   ||
|| 9   ||  30   ||    || 9   ||  10   ||
||==============||    ||==============||
```

I need to search for Top 5 highest value but instead of only 5 result I need those 7 users with 50 and 40 values.

I cant just disregard they other Top users.
If possible to be done in SQL that would be great. if not A help on PHP will do.

```
     Result 1              Result 1
||==============||    ||==============||
||user || value ||    ||user || value ||
||-----||-------||    ||-----||-------||
|| 1   ||  50   ||    || 1   ||  50   ||
|| 2   ||  50   ||    || 2   ||  50   ||
|| 3   ||  50   ||    || 3   ||  50   ||
|| 4   ||  40   ||    || 4   ||  50   ||
|| 5   ||  40   ||    || 5   ||  50   ||
|| 6   ||  40   ||    ||==============||
|| 7   ||  40   ||
||==============||
```

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want the top 5 or the top 7? Show what your expected result is from this hypothetical query.

Comment: @wavemode What he wants is the top 5 plus ties.

Comment: Oh okay, the original only showed Database 1.

Comment: What is the second table for?

Comment: I thought the second result was the desired results for the second database. But now I'm not sure. Why are all the values in the second result `50`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT user, value
FROM Database
WHERE value in (
    SELECT value
    FROM Database
    ORDER BY value DESC
    LIMIT 5)
)
ORDER BY value DESC, user
```

Another way is:

```
SELECT user, value
FROM Database
WHERE value >= (SELECT MIN(value)
                FROM (SELECT value
                      FROM Database
                      ORDER BY value DESC
                      LIMIT 5) AS x
                )
ORDER BY value DESC, user
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, for a given table, you can do:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT t.*
      FROM table t
      ORDER BY value DESC
      LIMIT 1 OFFSET 4
     ) t5
WHERE t.value >= t5.value;
```

The subquery chooses the fifth row (`OFFSET` starts counting at 0 rather than 1).  The `where` clause just chooses anything larger than that value.

If you want to run this on two tables combined, then you would want to use `union all`.

Comment: +1 I didn't think of the OFFSET option in my answer.